# Deep link is not working at chrome expo react native project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, deep-linking

Am integrated Deeplink in my expo project and i tried to open app with deeplink in chrome its not working. Actually i need to send the link in mail, when user click the link then i want app should open. Androidmainfest file

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Exponent.Splash"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="mychatapp" android:host="inbox" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i Added same scheme to my React native app.json
  `"scheme": "mychatapp"` and App.js i added

this is my code. I tried all the way to run deep link in chrome but its not working. Please tell where am doing mistake on it.

Answer (score -1):

[good example](https://github.com/AnkitDroidGit/ReactNative-Deeplink)

Very easy... try...
In my case works... but not open the correct screen